# autocomplete search in ng-repeat in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I my code i have 3 ng-repeats based on key press event value i am getting data from service and iam consuming
my html code is:

```
<div class="input-group" ng-controller="sidemenu">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter location, builder or project"  ng-model="NodeId_1" autofocus  ng-keyup="getValue($event.keyCode)"/>
    <div class="search-datalist" ng-if="showsearch">
        <ul ng-if="resultOfBuldDet.length>0">
            <span class="result-hd">Builders</span>
            <li  ng-repeat="bud in resultOfBuldDet" ng-class="{active :2}" ng-click="searchFilter(bud)"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> {{bud.builders_name}}</li>
        </ul>
        <ul ng-if="resultOfPropDet.length>0">
            <span class="result-hd">Properties</span>
            <li ng-repeat="prop in resultOfPropDet" ng-click="searchFilter(prop)"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> {{prop.property_name}} ,{{prop.hp_city.city_name}},{{prop.hp_location.location_name}} </li>  
        </ul>
        <ul ng-if="resultOfCityDet.length>0">
            <span class="result-hd">cities</span>
            <li ng-repeat="city in resultOfCityDet" ng-click="searchFilter(city)"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"> </i> {{city.city_name}}</li>
        </ul>
        <ul ng-if="resultOfLocaDet.length>0">
            <span class="result-hd">Location</span>
            <li ng-repeat="loc in resultOfLocaDet" ng-click="searchFilter(loc)"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> {{loc.location_name}},{{loc.hp_city.city_name}}</li>
        </ul>   
        <ul ng-if="resultOfSubLocaDet.length>0">
            <span class="result-hd">sub Location</span> 
            <li ng-repeat="subloc in resultOfSubLocaDet" ng-click=" searchFilter(subloc)"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> {{subloc.sub_location_name}},{{subloc.hp_location.location_name}},{{subloc.hp_location.hp_city.city_name}}</li>
        </ul>         
    </div>
</div>
```

my controller js code:

```
 sidemenu.controller('sidemenu', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'allServices'

        function(a, b,e) {

  a.getValue = function(key) {
            if (key == 8 && a.NodeId_1.length <= 2) {

                a.resultOfPropDet = "";
                a.resultOfBuldDet = "";
                a.resultOfLocaDet = "";
                a.resultOfCityDet = "";
                a.resultOfSubLocaDet = "";
            }

            if (a.NodeId_1.length > 2) {
                e.searchList(a.NodeId_1).then(function(result) {
                    a.resultOfPropDet = result.data.resultOfPropDet;
                    a.resultOfBuldDet = result.data.resultOfBuldDet;
                    a.resultOfLocaDet = result.data.resultOfLocaDet;
                    a.resultOfCityDet = result.data.resultOfCityDet;
                    a.resultOfSubLocaDet = result.data.resultOfSubLocaDet;
                    a.showsearch = true;
                }, function(error) {

                });
            }
        }



});
```

so when i am moving up and down arrows in keyboard.how to highlight the particular rows and trigger the particular function
like this [image]

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: @pedromarce ,thanq for the reply ,not questioning .actually that code is totally working for mouse based events but i  want to handle with key up and key down events also

Comment: you can use ng-keyup=" searchFilter()" and ng-keydown=" searchFilter()" to achieve the same as ng-click on key up and down events

Comment: sorry not key up and key down,.based on keyboard  arrow marks .the paritcular one has to highlight and move up and down